# LG G3 doesn't use image from xxxhdpi if there are alternatives — as a result, image is blurred

Tags: android, scala, sbt, dpi

Say, I have an ImageView with both sizes set to `wrap_content`, and it has some image: `android:src="@drawable/xyz"`.

If this image appears only in `xxxhdpi` folder, then everything is fine. However, if it appears in **any** of the other drawable directories (xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, or even sw320dp), then it doesn't use the image from xxxhdpi and, as a result, the image is blurred. (it's not easy to notice, *but I can notice this and I don't think QHD displays make any sense if their full resolution is not used*)

Is it possible to solve this issue without resorting to multiple APKs?

More precisely, this is LG D856 phone (dual SIM), with Android 4.4.2.

#### update

This is weird, but if I create project in Android Studio instead of this tool for coding for Android in Scala, then there's no such issue…

#### update 2

APK file: http://dropbox.com/s/lqdj9w7iimh2gj9/magicgoose-example-debug.apk?dl=0
Source code: http://dropbox.com/s/cs4pngpkvkoe5q2/dpi-example-src.zip?dl=0

Source can be built using SBT (scala build tool)
I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin

Comment: Did you try in an emulator ? Is this problem specific to your device ?

Comment: @ShaiLevy I don't have any other xxxhdpi devices, so I can't say this. I will try it on emulator, but the phone is a different beast (it doesn't use "pure" Android, but with unknown manufacturer's modifications), so I doubt that emulator's result will add anything here…

Comment: I know emulator is a didrent beast, I'm first trying to figure if the problem is with the project code or the device execution. just a first step.

You won't need multiple APK anyway, you can patch it manually by putting the same drawable with a different name and some code to select it. Or maybe take a peek on the new mipmap directory structure and look for a solutions there

Comment: in Genymotion I can't even select 640dpi density (it has 480 maximum)

Comment: You can use a normal emulator.

Comment: > "Or maybe take a peek on the new mipmap directory structure and look for a solutions there" — sounds interesting, never heard this.

Comment: Also, feel free to send me an APK and I can test on my G3, just add a visual element that identifies the image used on the picture file (different in each dir)

Comment: @ShaiLevy thank you, I will try to search these things, and if nothing helps, I will prepare APK for you.

Comment: this is weird, but if I create project in Android Studio instead of https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin, then there's no such issue…

Comment: @ShaiLevy https://www.dropbox.com/s/lqdj9w7iimh2gj9/magicgoose-example-debug.apk?dl=0 This is the problematic APK. And this is the source: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cs4pngpkvkoe5q2/dpi-example-src.zip?dl=0

Comment: Image 1 is blurred and image 2 is great (G3, Lollipop, stock rom) .. Why don't you use Android Studio ? I don't know the plugin you are using but its pretty clear its the source of the problem

Comment: Because I write in Scala and AS doesn't work well with Scala.

Comment: Oh... so you should probably re-tag the question and also open an issue in the github of the plugin, I think it will improve the chance of a workaround or fix

Comment: @ShaiLevy done. https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin/issues/146

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71269/discussion-between-sarge-borsch-and-shai-levy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in that the plugin did set target API level to 1 by default. When I set it explicitly to 21, the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

read here:

http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

> Provide an xxx-high-density launcher icon
>
> Some devices scale-up the launcher icon by as much as 25%. For
>   example, if your highest density launcher icon image is already
>   extra-extra-high density, the scaling process will make it appear less
>   crisp. So you should provide a higher density launcher icon in the
>   drawable-xxxhdpi directory, which the system uses instead of scaling
>   up a smaller version of the icon.
>
> Note: the drawable-xxxhdpi qualifier is necessary only to provide a
>   launcher icon that can appear larger than usual on an xxhdpi device.
>   **You do not need to provide xxxhdpi assets for all your app's images.**

I know for some cases you really wish it used the `xxx` but what I understand for this text is: "Android only uses `xxx` for the launcher icon and nothing more." So I believe you'll have to find some work around (e.g. set a bigger PNG and scale it down on the ImageView, or mipmaps) until Android as a platform uses the triple X everywhere.